# I'm not sure what stats test I should be using

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I'm trying to see whether the colour of a trap affects how many fish are caught in the trap.

The independent variable is colour with 5 categories (5 colours). 
The dependant variable is number of fish caught with 18 categories (18 different species of fish). 
I also have 12 independent replicates - same experiment was done at 12 different ponds.

I don't know what stats test I can use that will test for colour preference in all 18 species and take into account the multiple sample sites.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. Strictly speaking, your data does not have multiple observations of the same random variable. Or in other words, many independent observations from identically distributed random variables. Not unless you make assumptions. For example, you may want to assume that probability of a fish of a particular specie will get caught in a particular color net is independent of pond. If you assume this then you have 18x5 sets of 12 observations each.